# Accidentally deleted Main.Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to follow directions in a Udacity class and when I did, it deleted the Main.Storyboard file in the project navigator (I don't think the file itself was deleted).  I read the popup but fat-fingered the delete button instead of backing out.    How can I get it back?
Note: I am extremely new to programming, FYI...

Comment: check out in trash if you pressed move to trash...

Comment: Are you using source control?  Just checkout the file.

Comment: Thanks for the hints,  I figured it out.  I accidentally deleted the reference and was able to bring it back.  Live and learn, right?

Comment: I even don't know why this question has been downvoted so much. Vote +1.

Answer (score 19):

I just happened to figure this out on my own.  In case anyone else runs into this issue:
Click file/open, navigate to your program folder, find Base.lproj, open Main.storyboard.  If the file isn't there, you probably deleted and need to restore it from the recycling bin.

Comment: You were lucky this time. You need to use Source Control, Git is built into Xcode with a very reasonable interface. Then setup a remote repository, there are free ones such as Bitbucket and GitHub. Sooner to later you will loose code and realize backups are necessary. Also consider using TimeMachine, it is super simple to setup and recover files from. Do it today, do not wait until you need it and it is to late. –  zaph just now   edit

Comment: Recycling bin :D You running Xcode on a PC? Thanks for your answer. Found it just as described in the Base.lproj folder