# How to add storyboard back to xcode after accidentally deleted

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard, xcode-project

I accidentally deleted my storyboard from the Xcode project. I followed this thread : [Accidentally deleted Main.Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758918/accidentally-deleted-main-storyboard) and fortunately I found it in Base.lproj folder.

But I'm having trouble to add it back to Xcode project. Since I'm new to iOS and Xcode still I couldn't add it back to my project. I can open it separately.

Can someone point me out how can I add it back to my project? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) What is iSO?  (2) Unless you spell out what you exactly mean by 'trouble,' no one can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. drag and drop it to Xcode's project navigator
2. uncheck "Copy items if needed"